# How to find "waves" in time-series data in R?

Tags: r, time-series

Good afternoon,

I have a vector of data (`force`) in which values increase from low values, to a peak value, and then to low values again (repeating this trend twice), then creating two "waves" of data.

This is the code, in which I plot the force vector as a function of `time` (for a better representation)

```
force <- c(0,0,0,0,3,4,5,3,0,6,8,9,10,14,21,25,12,10,8,5,0,4,3,4,6,0,3,15,20,24,50,80,150,180,200,250,332,369,470,578,690,540,444,378,299,254,200,130,79,55,29,17,4,5,2,7,8,3,5,7,6,1,2,9,11,20,23,15,4,5,6,8,18,20,29,40,55,69,100,144,189,245,300,415,555,696,500,434,321,279,249,150,130,68,50,43,23,19,4,5,4,5,3,2,0,5,3,4)
time <- seq(from=0, to=length(force)-1, by=1)
plot(time,force, type = "l", lty = 1)
```

What I would like to do is to cut the vector so as it only contains the two "waves" of data. A "wave" is defined when:

1. First, data goes above 20
2. Then, a threshold of 300 is crossed
3. Finally, data goes below 20 again

So according to these criteria, a wave would be found every time the data goes above 20, crosses a certain threshold, in this case 300 and afterwards goes below 20.

Done manually, the `force.cut` vector would be the desired result:

```
force.cut <- c(force[29:52],force[74:97])
time.cut <- seq(from=0, to=length(force.cut)-1, by=1)
plot(time.cut,force.cut, type = "l", lty = 1)
```

I am almost sure that the `findpeaks` function from the `pracma` package should be part of the solution, but I have not found the way to do exactly what I need. I am sure that there should be an easy way to do it, though.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick try:

```r
force <- c(0,0,0,0,3,4,5,3,0,6,8,9,10,14,21,25,12,10,8,5,0,4,3,4,6,0,3,15,20,24,50,80,150,180,200,250,332,369,470,578,690,540,444,378,299,254,200,130,79,55,29,17,4,5,2,7,8,3,5,7,6,1,2,9,11,20,23,15,4,5,6,8,18,20,29,40,55,69,100,144,189,245,300,415,555,696,500,434,321,279,249,150,130,68,50,43,23,19,4,5,4,5,3,2,0,5,3,4)
time <- seq(from=0, to=length(force)-1, by=1)
plot(time,force, type = "l", lty = 1)
```

[image]

```r
a <- pracma::findpeaks(force, minpeakheight = 301, threshold = 20)
a
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]  690   41   26   53
#> [2,]  696   86   69   99

plot(time, force, xlim =c(a[1,3], a[1,4]), type = "l")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

EDIT:

as the `findpeaks()` returns the start and stop position of the peak, not the threshold, you can search the position of thresholds on the left and right side of the peak, like:

```r
a <- pracma::findpeaks(force, minpeakheight = 301, threshold = 20)
a
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]  690   41   26   53
#> [2,]  696   86   69   99
left <- force[a[1,3]:a[1,2]]
left
#>  [1]   0   3  15  20  24  50  80 150 180 200 250 332 369 470 578 690
which(left >= 20)
#>  [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
l <- length(which(left >= 20))
l <- a[1,2]-l+1
force[l:a[1,2]]
#>  [1]  20  24  50  80 150 180 200 250 332 369 470 578 690
```

Just an idea, but hopefully makes sense.

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, I am sorry for the late response, but I was trying with your suggestions and could not find the way to do what I am trying to. I explain you why. From the plot it looks like the solution is correct. However, I think the problem is that the threshold apply to the index, and not the values of the vector. In fact, in your function: plot(time, force, xlim =c(a[1,3], a[1,4]), type = "l"), a[1,3] corresponds to the value 0 of the vector force[26], while a[1,4] correspond to the value 7 of the vector force[53]. What I would need is to take the first value above 20 with a peak afterwards

Comment: which would be force[30], which equals 24, and also take the last value as the first value below 20 after the intended peak (301) is reached, which would be force[52], which equals to 17. And repeat this process for the second wave. I am not sure if I explain myself correctly, can you see what I would need? Basically, a[1,3] should be 30, while a[1,4] should be 52. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Ah, you are right, it returns the position where the peeks starts and ends, not necessary the position of threshold. Extending the answer a bit.

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, thank you very much for this. It solved the problems I mentioned here, but I found some more troubles with this funcion. I decided to use findpeaks from the ggsignal package instead and it was more straightforward and efficient finding peaks in the database I was working with. Anyway, thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using a for loop...

```r
library(pracma)

peaks <- findpeaks(force, threshold = 20, minpeakheight = 300)


peak_period <- colSums(peaks)[4] - colSums(peaks)[3] + nrow(peaks)



peak_vec <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = peak_period)

w_start <- 1

for(i in seq_len(nrow(peaks))){
  
  len_i <- length(peaks[i, 3] : peaks[i, 4])
  w_end <- w_start + len_i-1
  peak_vec[w_start:w_end] <- c(peaks[i, 3]:peaks[i, 4])
  w_start <- len_i + w_start
  
}


plot(1:peak_period, force[peak_vec], type = "l", lty = 1, ylab = "Force", xlab = "Time")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you very much for your response, but I find the same problem with your solution that in the one proposed earlier: look at my comment to know which the problem is. Thank you so much!